# How to determine if an application is running as a mobile or desktop air applicaton?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, air, adobe

How can I find out what the current application type is? i.e. whether it's running on a mobile device or as a desktop Air application?

I've tried this:

```
if(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplicatoin as WindowedApplication)
 //desktop
```

However the mobile Version can't find the `WindowedApplication` class.

How do I tell the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok this works:

```
public static function isAndroid():Boolean
{
    return (Capabilities.version.substr(0,3) == "AND");
}
public static function isIOS():Boolean
{
    return (Capabilities.version.substr(0,3) == "IOS");
}
 ... //is Blackberry

public static function isMobile():Boolean
{
    return (isAndroid() || isIOS()); // || isBlackberry()
}
```

Comment: public static function get isBlackBerry():Boolean
{
    return (Capabilities.version.substr(0,3) == "QNX");
}

Comment: Defining "beeing a mobile" as being "Android" or "IOs" is terribly wrong. Whatever platforms you add to the list, the approach is simlply wrong. Keeping a list of possible mobile platforms up to date forever is a very bad idea

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Capabilities.OS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os); however heed this warning from the docs:

> Do not use Capabilities.os or Capabilities.manufacturer to determine a
>   capability based on the operating system. Basing a capability on the
>   operating system is a bad idea, since it can lead to problems if an
>   application does not consider all potential target operating systems.
>   Instead, use the property corresponding to the capability for which
>   you are testing.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I suppose that would make testing hard.  I don't have a solution for that, though.  Lots of issues w/ simulator.  But, file an enhancement request and I'll vote for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know whether you are running on mobile or desktop you should check for `Capabilities.cpuArchitecture:`

```
if(Capabilities.cpuArchitecture=="ARM")
{
  
}
```

Comment: Does this work correctly for Intel x86 Android phones? Like the ASUS ZenFone?

Answer (score 1):

This is the class I use for determine which os is it and if it's Mobile or not, of course this only covers Windows, Linux Android and iOS:

```
package com.fw3dlogical.utils {

    import flash.system.Capabilities;

    /**
     * Platform
     * @author Juan Fernando Velez
     */
    public class Platform {

            public static function get isWin():Boolean {
                return (Capabilities.version.indexOf("WIN") != -1);
            }

            public static function get isLinux():Boolean {
                return (Capabilities.version.indexOf("LNX") != -1);
            }

            public static function get isAndroid():Boolean {
                return (Capabilities.version.indexOf("AND") != -1);
            }

            public static function get isiOS():Boolean {
                return (Capabilities.version.indexOf("IOS") != -1);
            }

            public static function isMobile():Boolean {
                return (isAndroid() || isiOS());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure,
But we can not convert FlexGlobals.topLevelApplicatinn into WindowedApplication in Mobile Application.

So, Mobile Applications can be from the following types:

1.TabbedViewNavigatorApplication - for Tabbed View Navigation Application

2.viewnavigatorapplication - view based navigation application

So as your application type you should try from above two options for conversion....

Comment: This is incomplete.  I have made Mobile Applications that extend Application; in fact I think that is even a wizard option in Flash Builder.

Answer (score 0):

This test will work from a mobile app without needing to test for specific OS names (like Capabilities.os or Capabilities.version). It has the advantage of working consistently when debugging a mobile app on the desktop as well where Capabilities.os may not give you the answer you want:

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
...

var hasWindowedApp:Boolean = false;
try
{
    hasWindowedApp = getDefinitionByName("spark.components.WindowedApplication") != null;
}
catch (error:ReferenceError)
{
}

if (!hasWindowedApp)
{
    try
    {
        hasWindowedApp = getDefinitionByName("mx.core.WindowedApplication") != null;
    }
    catch (error:ReferenceError)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

C# Function to check IOS(iPad, iPhone)

```
    public bool isIOS()
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

        if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] != null)
        {
            foreach (string s in new[] { "iPad", "iphone" })
            {
                if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the method shown in the accepted answer?

Comment: The original question is about AIR/AS3, not ASP.NET/C#