# How to tell if Flash AS3 is running in desktop or mobile browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, browser, mobile, desktop

I am developing a full-Flash site (Player 10.2).

I need to know at runtime if code is running on a desktop/mouse computer or a mobile/touch device, so that I can differentiate the input mechanism.

Is this by any means possible?

Comment: Why? Aren't the inputs still considered click events?

Comment: No, for desktop I am also using "MOUSE_MOVE" in a way that it can't be used with "touch" input. When I am moving the mouse to the left, the screen scrolls to the left and vice versa...

Comment: See also [How to determine if an application is running as a mobile or desktop air applicaton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404071/how-to-determine-if-an-application-is-running-as-a-mobile-or-desktop-air-applica/10523385#10523385) on this site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's [flash.system.Capabilities.version](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#version) look?

Comment: That's better I suppose. Anyway, for my case, I think I'm gonna end up with "Capabilities.touchscreenType".

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Windows 7 natively supports multitouch input monitors so you can still come up with "touch screen" even on a desktop machine. User1113426 answered your question accurately.

Comment: How come? There is no "Android" option as return value... or is there?! http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os

Answer (score 4):

Use [flash.system.Capabilities.os](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os) to check.

Comment: Hmm, it never returns "Android" as OS! Maybe I should check the ".cpuArchitecture" property instead and see if it returns "ARM"? That ain't accurate either... :-(

Comment: He gave you the answer. You check for OS. It will tell you if it is android, ios, windows, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For AIR 3.9: Capabilities.manufacturer returns "Adobe iOS" on ipad2, "Android Linux" on Galaxy s4. Capabilities.version returns "IOS 11,9,900,117" on ipad2 and "AND 11,9,900,117" on Galaxy s4.

Answer (score 1):

You could check to see if the device has accelerometer support. If so, you know it's a mobile device. I dont know exactly what it is you would like to do so I dont know if this will work well for your project. It will distinguish mobile from desktop, though.

```
if(Accelerometer.isSupported){
    //mobile device
    //os still unknown
else{
    //desktop or laptop
    //os still unknown
}
```