# button that links to different URL for mobile and desktop in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I created a simple animation in Flash with AS3.  I have a button that needs to send people to one URL if they are on a desktop, and another if they are on a mobile device.  My coding skills are really sad and limited.  Can anyone tell me if that is possible, and what script I would use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811871/how-to-tell-if-flash-as3-is-running-in-desktop-or-mobile-browser When the user clicks the button you can check what kind of device they're using, and send them to the URL for that device.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(stage.stageWidth > 500){
    navigateToURL(desktop link);
}else{
    navigateToURL(mobile link);
}
```

clear.